# How do I access a map of vector<int> to int?

Tags: c++

I have a piece of code, where I created a map from vector to int.

I iterate over the map with auto but even though I can access the size of the vector, I cannot push to the key.

Is that not allowed?

```
    int numberOfArithmeticSlices(vector<int>& A) {
        map<vector<int>, int> m;
        for(int i=0; i<A.size(); i++){
            m[{A[i]}] = 0;
            for(auto it: m){
                if(it.first.size() == 1){
                    it.first.push_back(A[i]);
                    it.second = A[i]-it.first[0];
                }
                else{
                    if(A[i]-it.first.back() == it.second){
                        it.first.push_back(A[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        int ans=0;
        for(auto it:m){
            if(it.first.size()>2)
                ans++;
        }
        return ans;
    }
```

The error I get is:
`no matching member function for call to push_back`

Comment: You cannot modify the keys in map, so yes, it's not allowed. Why do you want to sort elements by vectors?

Comment: you might want to avoid using one-letter variables and give them meaningful names instead. It makes your code very difficult to understand. I am pondering if there might be an alternative solution to your problem, but it's hard to tell when I don't understand what your code is even supposed to do.

Comment: To change the key of an element in a map, remove the old key from the map, change the key, insert the new key-value pair.

Comment: If you are working on [this problem from LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/arithmetic-slices/), then I recommend a different approach: 1. Find a way to generate all the subsequences of the sequence. 2. Then find out which of these subsequences are arithmetic slices and count them.

Comment: When you do `for(auto it: m)` you are operating on *copies* of m's elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change the value of a key in `std :: map` once it has been  added to the map. The only way out is to `erase` the key and re-insert it after making the changes.

Look [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase) up to know how to erase a key from a `std :: map`.

Comment: If you use a pointer to a vector as a key, then you have pointers as keys, instead of vectors as keys. It's a completely different map, then.

Comment: @user253751 but the job can be done more efficiently then. Even though the mapping scheme has been changed, we have brought down the O(n) re-insertion time to O(1) time, where n is the number of elements in the vector that's used as a key during re-insertion into the map.

Comment: but now your keys don't compare the same. Now you're storing things in the map based on memory address instead of based on the contents of the vector. You can customize how the map compares keys, to fix that, but you still have to remove and reinsert the entry when you change the vector.

Comment: I see, I didn't consider that. I'm removing that part from my answer. Then, the rest of it looks correct, isn't it?